# Fantasy rule of propositional logic in first order logic

Tags: propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, second-order-logic

The fantasy rule in propositional logic is

Fantasy Rule: If assuming $A$ to be a theorem leads to $B$ being a theorem, then $<A⊃B>$ is a theorem.

An example is

$$
\begin{align}
&[\\
& & &<p∧q>          \tag{assumption}\\
& & &p              \tag{separation}\\
& & &q              \tag{separation}\\
& & &<q∧p>          \tag{joining}\\
&]\\
&<<p∧q>⊃<q∧p>>    \tag{fantasy}
\end{align}
$$

How would I express the fantasy rule more formally using  first or second order logic notation?

Comment: I'm curious, where did you hear this called the "fantasy rule?" (I found [a blog post](http://scientiststhesis.tumblr.com/post/51568477316/propositional-logic) calling it that, but nothing else.)

Comment: @Noah I learned propositional logic from this page http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/propositionallogic/

Comment: I just stumbled upon this name in GEB (page 183) , this is what brought me here in fact, I was looking for the name if it is popular in Academia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Conditional Introduction, or Conditional Proof, which is a well known principle in Propositional logic. First-order logic simply borrows this rule from propositional logic, so the rule is the same there.

There is no first-order logic description of this rule, since the rule is a rule *about* logic statements (first-order logic statements, in the case of firs-order logic): it states how some logic staement can be derived from other logic statements or proof structures.

Thus, it is typically represented using text, or some kind of depiction, not unlike what you have:

| $\phi$ Assumption

| ...

| ...

| $\psi$

$\phi \rightarrow \psi \quad$ $\rightarrow \ $ Intro

Comment: I stated the rule using text. Can the rule be stated more formally using first order syntax. Or must we use text to write it down?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay Most texts will provide some kind of depiction of the rule ( not unlike what you did), and add some further text to explain it. There is no further first-order logic description of it, since it is really a meta-statement *about* the derivability of logic statements from other logic statements.

Comment: It also differ from many rules in that usually the assumptions can get stated as belonging to a set and then the conclusion stated.  Sometimes stated in a form like {p, (p -> q)} $\vdash$ q.  But, with the conditional introduction rule the dots happen by necessity, and the order matters since the assumption has to come first, so we don't have a premiss set where the members can changer order, but rather a sequence.